# If URL contains anchor link check matching checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, anchor

Is it possible to see if a URL contains a hash anchor link

```
sitelink.com/page#example
```

Then check the matching checkbox on the page

```
<input type="checkbox" value="example" id="example">
```

Comment: you mean the sharp sign ? **#**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash) contains the fragment after `#` plus the `#` itself

Just use it as selector and set the `checked` property

```
$(function() {
    $(window.location.hash).prop("checked", true);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//var url = 'sitelink.com/page#example';
var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);

$('input[type=checkbox][value="'+anchor +'"]').prop("checked",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var link = document.location.href.split('#');
if(link.length==2)
{
    var id = '#' + link[1];
    if($(id).length!=0)
         $(id).attr('checked',true);
}
```